# Tablayout in fragment is not showing tabs using view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying to add 2 tabs in fragment using view pager and view pager adapter but they aren't showing.

```
[![this is how it looks, no tabs are showing][1]][1]
```

this is **fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.code.erum.masterappeverycatalogdemo.activity.LatestBrandsFragment">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my **ViewPagerAdapter** class , it adds fragments in fragment list

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }
```

This is my **home** Fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }

        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new LastestCatalogsFragment(), "ONE");
            adapter.addFragment(new LatestBrandsFragment(), "TWO");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

This is **gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

          android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.code.erum.masterappeverycatalogdemo"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22+'
        }
```

Comment: Give tablayout fixed height. Also check the layout xml ill paste in answer below

Answer (score 1):

**Change This:**

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    FragmentManager FManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(FManager);

    // ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"  tools:context="com.code.erum.masterappeverycatalogdemo.activity.LatestBrandsFragment">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```